# C# Entity Framework: How do I update a record and change foreign key reference?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables:

Clients  (id, clientname)
Projects (id, clientid, projecttitle) foreign key reference clientid -> clients.id

When I load a project with EF like this:

```
thisProject = (from p in dataEntity.projects.Include("client")
               where p.id == INTVALUE
               select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then I change some values in thisProject, and would like to change the relationship to a diferent client, it will not allow me to modify the clientid field in the Projects table.

Hope I explained this well enough, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
var thisProject = (from p in dataEntity.projects.Include("client")
               where p.id == INTVALUE
               select p).FirstOrDefault();

var newClient = dataEntity.clients.FirstOrDefault(); // change to suit
thisProject.Client = newClient;
```

You can't just change the EntityKey AFAIK - you need to actually change the navigational reference.

HTH.

Comment: Great, glad you got it sorted.